# Swift: Get multiple array values like "x"

Tags: arrays, swift

For example, I have an array like `var myArray = ['player_static.png', 'player_run0.png', 'player_run1.png', 'player_run2.png', 'player_jump0.png', 'player_jump1.png']`

Is there any simple way to get only the "player_runX.png" images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter to get all elements that hasPrefix("player_run"):

```
let myArray = ["player_static.png", "player_run0.png", "player_run1.png", "player_run2.png", "player_jump0.png", "player_jump1.png"]

let playerRuns = myArray.filter{$0.hasPrefix("player_run")}
print(playerRuns)  //["player_run0.png", "player_run1.png", "player_run2.png"]
```

Comment: like some music producers say: less is more. 
thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to iterate over the array and retrieve the elements that match the pattern. A very quick sample would be something like this:

```
var myArray = ["player_static.png", "player_run0.png", "player_run1.png", "player_run2.png", "player_jump0.png", "player_jump1.png"]

func getSubArray(array:[String],prefix:String) -> [String]
{
    var newArray = [String]()
    for img in array
    {
        if img.substringToIndex(img.startIndex.advancedBy(prefix.characters.count)) == prefix
        {
            newArray.append(img)
        }
    }
    return newArray
}

var test = getSubArray(myArray, prefix: "player_run")
```